# Can I Pass Arguments To A Powershell Function The Unix Way?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a PowerShell function that basically looks like this:

```
function DoSomething-ToTask {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
          [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
          [strehg[]]$TaskNums
    )

    foreach ($TaskNum in $TaskNums) {
        do something $TaskNum
    }
}
```

The goal is to be able to be able to call this function from the command line with an arbitrary number of parameters. For example, I may call it like this now:

```
DoSomething-ToTask 1 2 3
```

..and like this later

```
DoSomething-ToTask 4
```

The second example works, but the first one does not. I have since learned that I need to pass multiple arguments like this:

```
DoSomething-ToTask (1, 2, 3)
```

Which isn't the worst thing in the world but still kind of a pain compared to the first example.

Is there any way to write a PS function that works with the "1 2 3" argument example?

Comment: As an aside: you don't need the `(...)` around `1, 2, 3` - in fact, doing so would make the syntax more cumbersome if the array elements were _strings_ - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63162649/45375).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `ValueFromRemainingArguments` parameter attribute.

```
function DoSomething-ToTask {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
          [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)]
          [int[]]$TaskNums
    )

    foreach ($TaskNum in $TaskNums) {
        do something $TaskNum
    }
}
```

Here is a working example:

```
function Do-Something { 
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)]
        [int[]] $TaskNumber
    )

    foreach ($Item in $TaskNumber) {
        Write-Verbose -Message ('Processing item: {0}' -f $Item);
    }
}

Do-Something 1 2 3 -Verbose;
```

Result:

[image]