# In powershell, how to build String arrays from "remaining" arguments passed from command line?

Tags: arrays, powershell, parameters

It is inconvenient to type ("arg0", "arg1", "arg2") on the command line when a function needs a String array. Like in this example:

```
function Exec-GradleScript(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]String] $ScriptName
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][String[]] $ArgList
    ){
    & "$ScriptName" $ArgList
}
```

... all the arguments after -ScriptName need to be in the explicit array syntax.
How can I avoid this, so that I can type

```
Exec-GradleScript foo.gradle arg0 arg1 arg2
```

And still have an $ArgList value to pass to the executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note:

- The solution is provided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21340261/45375), which shows how to use the `ValueFromRemainingArguments` parameter property to collect all individual unbound positional arguments in a single array parameter.
- I presume your function is simplified; as written, implementing the solution in the linked answer essentially makes the function unnecessary - you can simply call
  `foo.gradle arg0 arg1 arg2` *directly* (assuming `foo.gradle` is directly executable, which is what your function suggests).
- As an aside: It's sufficient to use `$ScriptName` rather than `"$ScriptName"`, because - unlike POSIX-like shells - PowerShell allows you to use variables *unquoted*, even if their value contains spaces or other shell metacharacters (no so-called shell expansions are performed).

---

As for:

> It is inconvenient to type ("arg0", "arg1", "arg2") on the command line when a function needs a String array.

**The cumbersome syntax `("arg0", "arg1", "arg2")` is only needed in *expression* parsing mode.**

**In *argument* parsing mode** - when you pass arguments to a *command* - **arrays can be passed using *much looser* syntax** - without parentheses and without quoting (unless the elements are *literals* that contain whitespace or PowerShell metacharacters, e.g., `'arg 0'`):

```bsh
# No parentheses around the array, elements unquoted.
Exec-GradleScript foo.gradle  arg0, arg1, arg2
```

For more information about PowerShell's two fundamental parsing modes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48779223/45375).